# Fails with error 1001 "Dropbox SDK v1.3.4" and "IOS 6.0"

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios6, sdk, dropbox

everyone. And always you very much.

Fails with error 1001 "Dropbox SDK v1.3.4" and "IOS 6.0"

"Upload.mov" is a file of 5MB.

```
NSString* filename = @"upload.mov";
NSString* destDir = @"test";
NSString* srcPath = @"test";
[restClient uploadFile:filename toPath:destDir withParentRev:nil fromPath:srcPath];
```

Consolelog

```
2013-07-09 06:53:13.110 DropBoxTest [13243:907] - (void) Start_Dropbox
2013-07-09 06:53:13.216 DropBoxTest [13243:907] if (! RestClient) {[DBRestClient alloc] initWithSession:
2013-07-09 06:53:17.365 DropBoxTest [13243:907] File upload restClient: uploadProgress - 0.006782
2013-07-09 06:53:17.370 DropBoxTest [13243:907] File upload restClient: uploadProgress - 0.013564
2013-07-09 06:53:17.373 DropBoxTest [13243:907] File upload restClient: uploadProgress - 0.020345
2013-07-09 06:53:17.374 DropBoxTest [13243:907] File upload restClient: uploadProgress - 0.027127
2013-07-09 06:53:51.652 DropBoxTest [13243:907] File upload restClient: uploadProgress - 0.033909
2013-07-09 06:53:51.656 DropBoxTest [13243:907] File upload restClient: uploadProgress - 0.040691
2013-07-09 06:53:51.657 DropBoxTest [13243:907] File upload restClient: uploadProgress - 0.047472
2013-07-09 06:53:51.660 DropBoxTest [13243:907] File upload restClient: uploadProgress - 0.054254
2013-07-09 06:53:51.662 DropBoxTest [13243:907] File upload restClient: uploadProgress - 0.061036
2013-07-09 06:53:51.665 DropBoxTest [13243:907] File upload restClient: uploadProgress - 0.067818
2013-07-09 06:53:51.668 DropBoxTest [13243:907] File upload restClient: uploadProgress - 0.074600
2013-07-09 06:53:51.671 DropBoxTest [13243:907] File upload restClient: uploadProgress - 0.081381
2013-07-09 06:53:51.674 DropBoxTest [13243:907] File upload restClient: uploadProgress - 0.088163
2013-07-09 06:53:51.677 DropBoxTest [13243:907] File upload restClient: uploadProgress - 0.094945
2013-07-09 06:53:51.679 DropBoxTest [13243:907] File upload restClient: uploadProgress - 0.101727
2013-07-09 06:53:51.682 DropBoxTest [13243:907] File upload restClient: uploadProgress - 0.108508
2013-07-09 06:54:40.271 DropBoxTest [13243:907] File upload restClient: uploadProgress - 0.115290
2013-07-09 06:55:40.320 DropBoxTest [13243:907] [WARNING] DropboxSDK: error making request to / 1/files_put/dropboxtestupload.mov - (-1001) Error Domain = NSURLErrorDomain Code = -1001 "The operation couldn 't be completed. (NSURLErrorDomain error -1001.) "UserInfo = 0x2087fb70 {destinationPath = test / upload.mov, sourcePath = upload.mov}
```

Uploading process is confirmed that you have progressed to the middle.
problem does not occur with iOS5.1.1. I successfully processed.
In iOS6.0, this problem has occurred.
What should I do now?

It seems to be a problem that depend on the terminal of the iPhone5.

The Exit menu to ensure the values ​​you selected transferred successfully.

```
iPhone4 iOS 6.1.3  ---->successfully.
iPhone4S iOS 5.1.1  ---->successfully.
iPad3 iOS 5.1.1  ---->successfully.
```

Exit by generating a 1001 error during file transfer of 5MB.

```
iPhone5 iOS 6.1.4  ---> Error
```

Dropbox SDK is, or would not correspond to the terminal of the iPhone5?

Comment: `NSURLErrorTimedOut`
Returned when an asynchronous operation times out.
`NSURLConnection` will send this error to its delegate when the timeoutInterval in `NSURLRequest` expires before a load can complete.`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Error -1001 on `NSURLDomain` is `NSURLErrorTimedOut`.

The default timeout set on Dropbox SDK is 20s.

Comment: Thank you!

How do I change from a program, the setting of the time-out Dropbox SDK?

Are there methods, properties like that?

However, in this issue, that only iPhone5 are worried about.

Comment: On line 1300 of `DBRestClient.m`, there's a `[urlRequest setTimeoutInterval:20];`. You could change that.

Comment: Thank you! The way out, I'd like there is only this way.

Comment: Hi, Marcelo Fabri,i am just adding frame work, please help us know how to settimeout,when we are just adding framework.

Answer (score 2):

Instead of playing around it with timeout, it's better we can redirect the file which fails to uploads, using uploadFileFailedWithError delegate of the Dropbox api.

I did the following to upload multiple files on drop box.

```
(void)restClient:(DBRestClient*)client uploadFileFailedWithError:(NSError*)error {


    NSLog(@"File upload failed with error - %@", error.userInfo);

    NSString *myfile=[error.userInfo valueForKey:@"sourcePath"];

    [self.restClient uploadFile:@"youfilename" toPath:@"/yourfilepath" withParentRev:nil fromPath:myfile];

}
```

This way the files which couldn't upload will get reattempt to get uploaded..

Comment: This would initiate an infinite loop of recursive Uploading Requests in case of repeated failed requests.

Answer (score 0):

I know this question is marked as solved but I found something on [DropboxCommunity](https://www.dropboxforum.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/201887309-Error-1001-The-operation-couldn-t-be-completed-) that can be helpful for future readers.

This error could arise when trying to upload big files (bigger than 150MB). If that's the case, better use uploadFileChunk instead of uploadFile.

So here it is a little snippet for more help:

```
// First call to the method upload_id must be nil, to tell it is a new upload
// offset is 0 (file is being upload from the beginning)    
[self.restClient uploadFileChunk:nil offset:0 fromPath:localFilePath];

// Every time a chunk is uploaded the DBRestClient delegate method will be called
- (void) restClient:(DBRestClient *)restClient
  uploadedFileChunk:(NSString *)uploadId
          newOffset:(unsigned long long)offset
           fromFile:(NSString *)localPath
            expires:(NSDate *)expiresDate {
    NSDictionary *attributes = [[NSFileManager defaultManager] attributesOfItemAtPath:localPath error:NULL];
    unsigned long long fileSize = [attributes fileSize]; // in bytes

// Meanwhile the new offset is smaller than the file size we keep uploading chunks
    if (offset < fileSize) {
        [self.restClient uploadFileChunk:uploadId offset:offset fromPath:localPath];
    }
// When all the chunks are in Dropbox, convert all the uploaded data to the file
    else {
        [self.restClient uploadFile:self.fileName
                             toPath:remoteParentFolder
                      withParentRev:self.parentRev
                       fromUploadId:uploadId];
    }
}
```